# WP_Query adds "(wp_posts.ID = '0')" so no results are returned

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql, query-posts, sql

I am doing a very simple WP_Query:

```
  $query = new WP_Query([
    'pagename'  => 'some-post-slug',
    'suppress_filters' => true // used by WPML to search in ANY language
  ]);
```

However, the query that is performed is:

```
 SELECT wp_posts.* 
 FROM   wp_posts 
 WHERE  1 = 1 
        AND ( wp_posts.id = '0' )  // notice this line
         AND wp_posts.id = 171073 
         AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
 ORDER  BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Why is `( wp_posts.id = '0' )` returned? If I remove it from the query, then the page is found without any issues.

Sidenote: Also strange that it searches by `wp_posts.id = 171073` when I defined a post_name.

Comment: Could it be that the SQL query you are looking at is not the one generated by your wp custom query. As both seem different ones.